# How do I add different types conforming to a protocol with an associated type to a collection?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, type-alias

As an exercise in learning I'm rewriting my [validation library](https://github.com/adamwaite/AJWValidator) in Swift.

I have a `ValidationRule` protocol that defines what individual rules should look like:

```
protocol ValidationRule {
    typealias InputType
    func validateInput(input: InputType) -> Bool
    //...
}
```

The associated type `InputType` defines the type of input to be validated (e.g String). It can be explicit or generic.

Here are two rules:

```
struct ValidationRuleLength: ValidationRule {
    typealias InputType = String
    //...
}

struct ValidationRuleCondition<T>: ValidationRule {   
    typealias InputType = T
    // ...
}
```

Elsewhere, I have a function that validates an input with a collection of `ValidationRule`s:

```
static func validate<R: ValidationRule>(input i: R.InputType, rules rs: [R]) -> ValidationResult {
    let errors = rs.filter { !$0.validateInput(i) }.map { $0.failureMessage }
    return errors.isEmpty ? .Valid : .Invalid(errors)
}
```

I thought this was going to work but the compiler disagrees.

In the following example, even though the input is a String, `rule1`'s `InputType` is a String, and `rule2`s `InputType` is a String...

```
func testThatItCanEvaluateMultipleRules() {

    let rule1 = ValidationRuleCondition<String>(failureMessage: "message1") { $0.characters.count > 0 }
    let rule2 = ValidationRuleLength(min: 1, failureMessage: "message2")

    let invalid = Validator.validate(input: "", rules: [rule1, rule2])
    XCTAssertEqual(invalid, .Invalid(["message1", "message2"]))

}
```

... I'm getting extremely helpful error message:

> _ is not convertible to ValidationRuleLength

which is cryptic but suggests that the types should be exactly equal?

So my question is... how do I append different types that all conform to a protocol with an associated type into a collection?

Unsure how to achieve what I'm attempting, or if it's even possible?

**EDIT**

Here's it is without context:

```
protocol Foo {
    typealias FooType
    func doSomething(thing: FooType)
}

class Bar<T>: Foo {
    typealias FooType = T
    func doSomething(thing: T) {
        print(thing)
    }
}

class Baz: Foo {
    typealias FooType = String
    func doSomething(thing: String) {
        print(thing)
    }
}

func doSomethingWithFoos<F: Foo>(thing: [F]) {
    print(thing)
}

let bar = Bar<String>()
let baz = Baz()
let foos: [Foo] = [bar, baz]

doSomethingWithFoos(foos)
```

Here we get:

> Protocol Foo can only be used as a generic constraint because it has
>   Self or associated type requirements.

I understand that. What I need to say is something like:

```
doSomethingWithFoos<F: Foo where F.FooType == F.FooType>(thing: [F]) {

}
```

Comment: What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: I'm using the very latest Swift 2

Comment: What is a ValidationResult? Please provide _enough code so that I can reproduce_.

Comment: Ok added a generic equivalent

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Protocols with type aliases cannot be used this way. Swift doesn't have a way to talk directly about meta-types like `ValidationRule` or `Array`. You can only deal with instantiations like `ValidationRule where...` or `Array<String>`. With typealiases, there's no way to get there directly. So we have to get there indirectly with type erasure.

Swift has several type-erasers. `AnySequence`, `AnyGenerator`, `AnyForwardIndex`, etc. These are generic versions of protocols. We can build our own `AnyValidationRule`:

```
struct AnyValidationRule<InputType>: ValidationRule {
    private let validator: (InputType) -> Bool
    init<Base: ValidationRule where Base.InputType == InputType>(_ base: Base) {
        validator = base.validate
    }
    func validate(input: InputType) -> Bool { return validator(input) }
}
```

The deep magic here is `validator`. It's possible that there's some other way to do type erasure without a closure, but that's the best way I know. (I also hate the fact that Swift cannot handle `validate` being a closure property. In Swift, property getters aren't proper methods. So you need the extra indirection layer of `validator`.)

With that in place, you can make the kinds of arrays you wanted:

```
let len = ValidationRuleLength()
len.validate("stuff")

let cond = ValidationRuleCondition<String>()
cond.validate("otherstuff")

let rules = [AnyValidationRule(len), AnyValidationRule(cond)]
let passed = rules.reduce(true) { $0 && $1.validate("combined") }
```

Note that type erasure doesn't throw away type safety. It just "erases" a layer of implementation detail. `AnyValidationRule<String>` is still different from `AnyValidationRule<Int>`, so this will fail:

```
let len = ValidationRuleLength()
let condInt = ValidationRuleCondition<Int>()
let badRules = [AnyValidationRule(len), AnyValidationRule(condInt)]
// error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks. I don't think I have ever seen anything like this before. Where did you learn that? Interested in reading some more.

Comment: My favorite source is the Swift header file itself. There's a ton of documentation in there, including quite a few "why"s if you read it carefully. And I spend a lot of time trying to build weird data structures and complaining about it on Twitter when they don't work and having @jckarter correct me. http://airspeedvelocity.net is also a very good source for the topics that interest me.

Comment: How come you need the closure and can't just store "base" and call validate on the stored base when you want to call validate?

Comment: @JPC the best way to understand that is to try implementing it. You'll find the wall almost instantly.