# Collection of <type implementing protocol> in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Consider this (simplified) program. I have a protocol `Thing` implemented in two structs, `ThingOne` and `ThingTwo`. I have a class `ThingCollection` that I would like to store arbitrary struct instances implementing the `Thing` protocol, meaning `ThingOne()` could be replaced with `ThingTwo()`. I have a class `ThingCollectionCollection` that I would like to store arbitrary instances of `ThingCollection`, regardless of its contained `Thing` instances:

```
protocol Thing: Equatable {

}

struct ThingOne: Thing {
    public static func ==(lhs: ThingOne, rhs: ThingOne) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

struct ThingTwo: Thing {
    public static func ==(lhs: ThingTwo, rhs: ThingTwo) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class ThingCollection {
    public var things: [Thing] = [ThingOne()] // Error here
}

class ThingCollectionCollection {
    var thingCollections: [ThingCollection] = [ThingCollection()]
}
```

In a Swift Playground, I get an error at `public var things: [Thing]` stating

> Protocol 'Thing' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.

This code works if protocol `Thing` inherits no other protocols, but in my case I do want implementations of `Thing` to be Equatable (and probably Hashable).

I suppose that I could make `ThingCollection` generic and use a different instance to store a single type of `Thing`, but then how could I store arbitrary `ThingCollection` instances in a `ThingCollectionCollection`? I am okay with an instance `ThingCollection` only being able to hold one type of `Thing`.

Comment: See also Rob Napier's blog post [about type erasers](http://robnapier.net/erasure).

Comment: The above blog post is really what helped me. The solution was using type erasers.

Comment: Although the bigger issue I have been facing is addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762045/how-do-i-add-different-types-conforming-to-a-protocol-with-an-associated-type-to ...