# Variable of generic protocol type in Swift 3

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Is it possible to declare a variable with the type of a generic protocol in Swift?

If no, what are the alternatives? It seems like a *huge* disadvantage that I cannot reuse a protocol with different type parameters, let alone mock it out.

Comment: You mean protocol with associated type?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve what generic interfaces achieve in so many other languages. So far my workaround is to create a base class with no real functionality and overwrite it in subclasses.

Comment: Ok, it's not possible to declare variable of protocol with associated type in Swift 1-3. But it looks like Generics will be improved in Swift 4. Check https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution.

Comment: I'll wait until late 2017 then ;-)

Comment: You're most likely looking for a [type erasure](http://robnapier.net/erasure) – see for example [How do I add different types conforming to a protocol with an associated type to a collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762045/how-do-i-add-different-types-conforming-to-a-protocol-with-an-associated-type-to)

Comment: Another solution I found so far is to wrap instances in generic structs, i.e. `MyContainer<T>` and then forward the constraints to the associated type of the contained instance. In this way, I don't need a "useless" base class with empty or error stub implementations, however, this adds programming overhead because all method calls need to be forwarded to the contained protocol instance.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you mean, but you can do:

`public typealias SuccessBlock<T>    = (_ data: T) -> (Void)`

and then define variables:

`var myBlock: SuccessBlock<String>`

Comment: Sure, but this is not an interface. It is just a type alias.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is non-generic protocol.
Agree about strange limitation thats hurts.
Limitation due to missing associatedtype is must use base of element in protocol, all other internal can be used with generic type

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Foundation

class Item: NSObject {

}

protocol Datasource {

    subscript(index: Int) -> NSObjectProtocol? { get }
}

class BaseDatasource<Element: NSObjectProtocol>: Datasource {

    private(set) var data: [Element]?

    subscript(index: Int) -> NSObjectProtocol? {
        get {
            return data?[index]
        }
    }

    func sortedData(_ data: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        return data
    }
}

class ItemsDatasource: BaseDatasource<Item> {
    ///some specific code
}

var dataOfInts: Datasource?

dataOfInts = ItemsDatasource()//or BaseDatasource<Item>()
```